# Error when I try to generate an access token

Tags: php, laravel

I have tried to generate an access token to authenticate in my API on a Laravel passport using Laravel 10. The token was generated successfully. But my token is wrong. I expected for token in this format:

`{`
 `"token": {`
 `"token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJhdWQiOiIxIiwianRpIjoiMmNhZTJiYWZiMGVkNWU5ZjIwYzg3MWQ1NTQ1ZDU2MGRmOWZlMjBkMGEzNTM3NDk5NjkwZWM4ZjE0MzVkNTFjZTc4ODFhZDlkYzU1MGI5OWIiLCJpYXQiOjE2ODI1MjE2NDAuNTczMzAyLCJuYmYiOjE2ODI1MjE2NDAuNTczMzA2LCJleHAiOjE3MTQxNDQwNDAuMjM2NDUsInN1YiI6IjEiLCJzY29wZXMiOltdfQ.B6mrtmeeSnaI_D7K0mvqZSE8VHu8JO6NveHLFVw4wNP6pjT3JeR5m2l51VFrQZA97ge-d75DfMmFjU66iCqjZgnCTn7zrcU59A7EUEkwLHL05uI2X-lIu4ljA21-iYECockQGtsWWtH-h7493JevYIM-jARz-jTEhj6Yk0VIEUQv1NV-n8W9Gu3J_7kq6sajuRpvTbcYPFOlBHoyba-VutdNmlZlMhC-3m2Gf0XQoPJ0kqAaucQ_Zz_SbKgyhEyQBamwkD35V6CV0fOsEie8S-YL8yKY-58ULzwHX4l9_Jn7zuPewtuLXcjoeXqBtzYUr8UqD7wWiFvoXpzmeUYzveUHmQqkEhxUvPjKIpAt2ME1uumNozX9jk6d1_vIvhBstn_DZgYudvtVBYJVDh9AMrbYwjS1GB16WBKFBl106OlnGIzM8a8ujf1i8c0QDwfYi06VBcpr927BnYBkfphi0kvhBJAQb9ke6HLAtvt9FJvD9XhCdNa0v5CXikn6QA4EAr5fpeKBOaM8-BKF03ObVkkimuXuZm5jTe60cfm1ShJWq7of1IbuKEJ0klH-mnkYEf05VMDWyrZdy1-hufEa9_AxLWOKZQ8U8-lthwdX1Thbo6hTadMWfi9zB4Z8ng6FErVZ2uvA4lWXLsKlDc5YmOqRsv70jStuI8Vjo_Y4Pw8"`
 `},`
`}`

But I got a token in this format: [image]

This is my auth service provider:

[image]

I expected for a access token in correct format. I know that correct access token has a lot of caracters more than my example.

Comment: how are you returning the token from this `AuthController`? and why are you expecting that particular format?